# Flask default values on IntegerField

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I want to create a form with an `IntegerField` which if left empty to assume its default values. I have tried to pass the form with `form = DefaultValuesForm(int_field = 10)` but this is inserting `10` to the field.

I want my field to be completely empty and if it is left empty by the user to send the default value with the POST request.

I am also using a placeholder to show to the user the default value.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   in my jinja2 template: `{{form.int_field(class = "form-control form-control-lg", placeholder="10")}}`

Comment: Why do not you test to see if the field is empty? In case it is empty then you take a default value (10)?: `if form.validate_on_submit(): x = form.int_field.data if x = ' ': x=10` ... or something in the genre?

Comment: this is exactly how I made it. :)